# Gaining control on the name of the temp file created in Java

Tags: java, file

Is there any way to control the random digits appended to a file name when a tempFile is created ? 
For eg. if I write `File.createTempFile("abc",".pdf")`, it creates a file with name `abc12323543121.pdf`. Instead of these digits, is it possible to append a timestamp ? I need this because for every file that i create, I need to append the timestamp to the file, which makes the file name quite long. So, instead of the randomly generated digits,if I could just use the timestamp, it would be really great.

Comment: Is there a reason you create the files as temporary files and not the normal way? That way you would have complete control over their names.

Comment: `createTempFile()` is resposible for making this filename unique even if you call it 1000 times in one second. It must be able to add some prefix or postfix.

Comment: @Philipp I ended up implementing it in the normal way, but in the system temp directory, which is more or less similar to the createTempFile method, but with more control on the random naming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the API does not directly provide this. But you can have a look into the `File.createTempFile()` source code to see how it is implemented, and then implement the required method yourself.

Basically, `createTempFile()` creates a `File` object with the intended file name, and then uses `FileSystem.createFileExclusively()` to create the file. This method returns `false` if the file already exists, in which case the file name is modified (by using a different random number) and the creation is retried.

You can follow the same approach, but note that `FileSystem` is a package private class, hence you can not use it in your own method. Use [`File.createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) instead to create the file atomically. This method also returns `false` in case the file already exists, so you can use it in a similar loop like `createTempFile()` uses the `createFileExclusively()` method.

Comment: I have implemented my own method to make a new file in the temp dir based on the inputs from both the answers.Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own utility method for creating temp file. Basically temp files are stored in temp directory like this :

```
public File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix){
     String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
     String fileName = (prefix != null ? prefix : "" ) + System.nanoTime() + (suffix != null ? suffix : "" ) ;
     return new File(tempDir, fileName);
}
```

Comment: I used the solution provided by Andreas to create a file atomically in the temp dir as suggested by you. Thank you.